# Evaluating trigonometric limits with variable exponent $\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^\frac1x$

Tags: calculus, limits

I found a set of problems of limits which i can't seem to work my way around.

I tried using the natural log and then applying L'Hospital's rule but I can't seem to make it work. 
The problem was to find the limit of the function of 
   $$\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^\frac1x$$
As x approaches 0
Please help me as there are some more problems like this. I cannot think of ways to evaluate them

Comment: [This handout](http://mathforum.org/kb/servlet/JiveServlet/download/206-2077549-7075099-600126/seq2.pdf) of mine on the topic from the late 1990s may be of use.

Comment: What happened when you used logs? Where did you get stuck? Try to use standard limit $\lim\limits _{t\to 0}\dfrac{\log(1+t)}{t}=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that (refer to this [**OP**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/936642/505767))

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^3}=\frac13 \implies \tan x=x+ \frac13x^3+o(x^3)$$

therefore

$$\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^\frac1x=\left(1+ \frac13x^2+o(x^2)\right)^\frac1x=\left[\left(1+ \frac13x^2+o(x^2)\right)^{\frac1{\frac13x^2+o(x^2)}}\right]^{\frac{\frac13x^2+o(x^2)}x}\to e^0=1$$

Frome the same derivation we can now easily derive that

$$\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^\frac1{x^2}\to \sqrt[3] e$$

Comment: Could you guide me to a proof of t^(1/t)->1 as t->0

Comment: that's wrong, $t^{1/t}\to 0$ as $t\to 0^+$

Comment: @PavelR. Thanks I obtain teh correct result in a completely wrong way! Now I've fixed the derivation :)

Comment: @user182947 Sorry for the confusion! Now it should be ok!

Comment: How Did you bring in 'e'. Did you use the definition of e?

Comment: @user182947 Yes exactly, recall that as $x t\to 0$ we have $(1+x)^\frac1x\to e$.

Comment: @gimusi What would be the limit of the same function if te exponent what 1/x^3 as x->0 the exponents of e wouldn't cancel out, help please

Comment: For $1/x^3$ the limit doesn’t exist indeed it is 0 for $x\to 0^-$ and it is $\infty$ for $x\to 0^+$. Can you see why? And for $1/x^4$?

Comment: The book that i used says the limit is infinity. So; does that mean the book is wrong or does infinity imply its limit doesn't exist?

Comment: @user182947 The limit as $x\to 0$ for $\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^\frac1{x^3}$ doesn't exist sonce  $x\to 0^+$ for $\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^\frac1{x^3}\to \infty$ but as $x\to 0^-$ for $\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)^\frac1{x^3}\to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

L'Hospital's rule is **not** the alpha and omega of limits computations!

To determine the limit of the logarithm,  use *Taylor's formula* at order $3$ for the tangent:
$$\frac{\tan x}x=\frac{x+\cfrac{x^3}3+o(x^3)}x=1+\frac{x^2}3+o(x^2),$$
so that
$$\frac1x\log\Bigl(\frac{\tan x}x\Bigr)=\frac1x\log\Bigl(1+\frac{x^2}3+o(x^2)\Bigr)=\frac1x\Bigl(\frac{x^2}3+o(x^2)\Bigr)=\frac{x}3+o(x)\to 0$$
and finally $\;\biggl(\dfrac{\tan x}x\biggr)^{\!\tfrac 1x}$ tends to $1$ as $x$ tends to $0$.

Comment: How did you remove the log? I didn't understand that

Comment: I simply used Taylor's polynomial for $\log(1+u)$ near $u=0$: it is $u+o(u)$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left( 1 + \frac{k}{x}\right)^x = \lim_{x \to 0^+} \left(1 + kx\right)^{1/x} = e^k$$ and for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $$0 < x < \delta \implies x < \tan x < x + \epsilon x^2.$$ Therefore, $$1 = \lim_{x \to 0^+} 1^x \leq \lim_{x \to 0^+} \left( \frac{\tan x}{x} \right)^{1/x} \leq \lim_{x \to 0^+} (1 + \epsilon x)^{1/x} = e^\epsilon.$$
Now take $\epsilon \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The limit of logarithm can be found without Taylor's formula:

$$
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)}{x}&=
\underbrace{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log\left(\frac{\tan x}{x}\right)}{\frac{\tan x}{x}-1}}_{=1}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\tan x}{x}-1}{x}
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\tan x}{x}-1}{x}
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x-x}{x^2}
\stackrel{\text{L'Hosp}}{=}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{\cos^2x}-1}{2x}\\[12pt]
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos^2x}{2x}
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2x}{2x}
=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{2}=0
\end{align*}
$$

The second limit is derived from the identity

$$
\lim_{t\to 1}\frac{\log t}{t-1}=1
$$

after substituion $t=\frac{\tan x}{x}$ as $x\to 0$.